# Text not getting rendered in React Web Applications

Tags: html, css, reactjs, render

I am trying to build a personal React web app by modularizing the *Hookup* template from *ColorLib*. However, React is not rendering the text components on-screen while images are getting displayed correctly. The text and the corresponding CSS styles are being mapped correctly, as I saw when I checked the DevTools.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Details extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <section className="ftco-section ftco-about ftco-no-pt ftco-no-pb" id="groom-bride-section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="wrap">
                <div className="row d-flex">
                  <div className="col-md-6 d-flex">
                    <div className="img d-flex align-self-stretch align-items-center" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/about.jpg)'}}>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-6 py-md-5 text">
                    <div className="py-md-4">
                      <div className="row justify-content-start pb-3">
                        <div className="col-md-12 ftco-animate p-4 p-lg-5 text-center">
                          <span className="subheading mb-4">Join us to celebrate <br />the wedding day of</span>
                          <h2 className="mb-4">Francisco <span>&amp;</span> Laura</h2>
                          <span className="icon flaticon-rose-variant-outline-with-vines" />
                          <span className="subheading">Which is celebration on</span>
                          <p className="time mb-4"><span>Dec | 28 | 2019</span></p>
                          <span className="subheading mb-5">Starting at 2:00 <br /> in the afternoon</span>
                          <span className="subheading mb-5">Saint John Paul Church <br /> in YorkNew.in</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

[image: the screenshot. text is supposed to appear to the right of the image]

[image: text being rendered, as seen in Dev Tools]

Any help on resolving the same is appreciated.

Comment: Is the bottom image a screenshot of your component's DOM, or that of Hookup? CAn you check the "computed" tab next to "styles", it'll show all the CSS rules being applied against that element and maybe what is styling it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the computed styles as @Drew Reese suggested, and {visibility: hidden, opacity: 0} styles were getting applies to the text. All I had to do was override the same. Thanks for the help!